# Challenge to uniquely identify a computer from any of its browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html, ip

In an HTML5 web app, I'm building a feature that relies on client-to-client communication (with pusher). It's made of PHP on the server-side and Javascript with Vue on the client side.

The typical scenario is: a window popup is opened, and from there it communicates directly with some other windows opened into *any* another browser on the same computer. Let's say you have 2 browsers installed, you open the web app popup with Firefox and it communicates with its web app sister page you did open previously into Chrome.

The only (half-)way we have found so far is to use the public IP address to build a private channel named with the IP address… It's basic and efficient.

However, if there is more than 1 computer connected to the same router, all of them will share the same public IP, and that's where things become difficult!

A solution could be to add the computer's local IP to the channel name (that was already built with the public IP), but despite a few nice workarounds I found to get this info from an initiated RTC Connection, this looks quite unreliable and often goes against browsers privacy rules…

Obviously, I cannot use session information with PHP on the server-side, nor cookies / local storage on the client-side, as all those solutions are tightly coupled with the browser itself (thank God Chrome won't share its cookies with Firefox on your computer). Those solutions would be perfect (and no need for a pusher) if we were using 1 single browser, but we need to handle multiple browsers on the same machine.

That's where I'm wondering if anyone would have already dealt with this design challenge and shared some tips, it would be awesome! Thanks for reading so far!

Comment: `thank God Chrome won't share its cookies with Firefox on your computer` - I think you're answering your own question here. There are good reasons that browsers act independently. As the server, all you have available is what the browsers send, and given that can all be controlled by the user, it isn't exactly reliable. Ultimately, I guess I'd ask; *why* can't you use sessions? Require each browser to log in, and tie the sessions together on the server-side using the username/etc. I often use two browsers **because** I want separate sessions. Anything that could bypass that would concern me.

Comment: Just to rule it out...any reason not to use websockets via the webserver? What are you doing which requires the peer-to-peer connection specifically?

Comment: Server Sessions have nothing to do with Chrome / Firefox, so if you want Chrome / Firefox to be seen as one host.  One idea is that in your first browser you give the user a unique reference generated Server Side,  give them the ability to save some sort of key file they can download, from the second browser give the user the option to load a key file.  The keyfile could have some sort of encryption / ShaSum, so sessions could not be hijacked.  Even better if you use SessionStorage, not LocalStorage you could have multiple windows from multiple Tabs / Browsers seen as separate or joined hosts.

Comment: The idea behind this is to give support teams a solution to hide automatically private/sensitive data when their customers share their screen. It works quite well but if we can't limit this behavior to a single end-user computer it would hide data from other users...

Comment: It's not clear why that requires a peer to peer network connection?

Comment: It could work without a peer to peer connection if we limited the feature to 1 browser that could easily communicate between its various windows, but to enable communication between different browsers, you need a bit more tooling like centralizing it from a server or a peer to peer connection, it's a bit the same challenge as building a chat app between 2 computers... My concern is to differentiate if that same chat app runs into 2 different browsers on the same computer or on 2 different computers.

Comment: So again, why peer to peer specifically? You just said yourself, it could be centralised from a server. So...why not websockets? Then the IP address issue just disappears

Comment: @ADyson maybe did I miss something here, could you put me on the right path? Assuming that there is no previous authentication, how can the server know with websockets that a Chrome window and a Firefox window belong to the same computer?

Comment: Well, why do they need to belong to the same computer? Why not have them belong to the same user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can check the user agent of the browser.
- You can check a combination of the request headers coming from different browsers.
- You can explicitly throw and catch an error in the user's browser and send it in the request header/body to determine what browser they're using.
- You can do canvas drawings to see the user's GPU/CPU information (since you're already using html5 that's a bonus).
- You can directly use webgl to do the same with perhaps different metrics (since canvas uses webgl anyways).
- You can check their typing speed or even build up a profile of their vocabulary and use of language.
- If you ask for permissions you can see all of their connected media devices like headphones, even just asking for audio permissions will show you all of them.
- You can benchmark their CPU with things like the time it takes to find primes or encrypt a key.
- You can use audio fingerprinting, which is almost as unique as your voice, since each browser and CPU architecture slightly differ in the digital pattern and oscillations created from audio, which can be captured.
- You can check their window size and screen size and screen resolution.
- There's probably even more I didn't think of now, you can also use any of them in combination to fingerprint a device.

For more information research browser sniffing and digital fingerprinting.  What's more is that you can uniquely identify the user across their own browsers on the same computer and also different users from different devices using a combination of browser sniffing/digital fingerprinting.

In your specific case you can't use all the browser sniffing techniques but you can still use some of them, like the user agent since it will still give you the user device information even if they're using a different browser.

The idea with digital fingerprinting is that you want to build up a probability high enough that you can be fairly certain it's the same user, you can't ever be truly sure, but sure enough.  Something like screen size doesn't mean much by itself, there's millions of devices using i.e. a size 1600 screen, however consider the following hypothetical example:

- User's device has screen size of 1600, that's i.e. ~1/8 users.
- User's device took 20ms to encrypt a 4096 key, that's i.e. ~1/8 users.
- User's device took 40ms to draw a canvas image, that's i.e. 1/8 users.

Now you already have a 8 * 8 * 8 = 1/512 probability of knowing what user it is and that value goes up way higher very quickly, based on 3 fundamentally unidentifiable things.

However it should be noted that using any browser sniffing or digital finger printing techniques like above fall under privacy regulations (at least in some countries).  A lot of things like the user agent is being deprecated and if you do things like this on a site you'll get into trouble with things like GDPR.  I believe you can get around that if you explicitly ask the user for their permission and let them know that i.e. their browser is being fingerprinted.  However you have to be careful because doing this can get you in trouble if it's malicious, doing things like this without a user's knowledge is unethical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this big list of tips @Matriarx, you get the idea! even if we can't be 100% accurate, getting a good probability to make things work is generally enough to cover quite a high percentage of use cases.